# jQuery UI - In Sortable, How we can control the element movement to x and y axis(both) only ?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

```
<html>
<body>
<div class='main'>
   <div class='sub'>Item 1</div>
   <div class='sub'>Item 2</div>
   <div class='sub'>Item 3</div>
   <div class='sub'>Item 4</div>
</div>

<script type='javascript'>
$('.main').sortable(
{
   //some code
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i can move element(sub) anywhere within or outside of main as i want like free painting ,But i want to control that movement of element only for x and y axis(both).  Please Help me.....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. it would help if you show us what layout are you expecting (by drawing a mock-up image of your desired output)

Answer (score 2):

may be you are looking for [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment)

**FROM DOCS**

It defines a bounding box that the sortable items are contrained to while dragging.